# SharePoint Sync Files

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sync

[image]

I want to be able to sync data from SharePoint 2013 to a server on our network. Basically sync documents, photos, txt files etc.

I have found a webpage that say to use the button (with circle) below - but on my SharePoint 2013 I don't have a button like this. Do I have to install or enable anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in SharePoint Foundation.

You need to be on Standard or Enterprise to enable Sync feature.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/42589b00-23f6-4be4-80fc-7ed012817850/is-skydrive-pro-available-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013-what-is-instead-if-not?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: can foundation be upgraded to standard?

Comment: @AndyBarker yes.http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16033.sharepoint-2013-migrate-from-sharepoint-foundation-2013-to-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

Comment: thanks for all your help. if we stay with Foundation, do you know of any 3rd party companies like bamboo that offer sync to network shares?